# Going back to master after rebase without any changes result in detached head

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

Working in git, want to go back to master. But i do not remember on which branch i have changes, but it does not matter. Everything what is important is already commited, so i want to go to my master branch, where everything is merged but it transfer me always to detached head. How can i force to switch to origin master?

--force or -f while checkout does not work.

Comment: What is the message that is returned when you try to `git checkout master` or `git switch master`?

Comment: fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'origin/master'

Answer (score 0):

To checkout or switch to branch, use `git checkout branchname` or `git switch branchname`, respectively (both commands do the same thing).

If a (local) branch does not exist yet, you have to create it first. You can either do it with a separate command:

```
git branch localbranch origin/remotebranch
git checkout localbrach # or: git switch localbranch
```

or with a command line switch:

```
git checkout -b localbranch origin/remotebranch
# or: git switch -c loalbranch origin/remotebranch
```